# Rails 4: loop for fields for

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, fields-for

Model is

```
has_many :questions
accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
```

Controller

```
params.require(:survey).permit(:title,:description,questions_attributes: [:title])
```

View is

```
<%= f.fields_for :questions,@survey.questions.build do |question| %>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-lg-12 control-label" for="">Title</label>
   <p><%= question.text_field :title %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

By this I only enter question just for one time.How I add multiple times question in it.I cant understand either I do it with JavaScript and make any button or which way I do this?

Comment: I want to add multiple question.By this code I able to add only one time.HOw I add multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple questions by using "nested_form" gem like this:-

```
# Add gem in Gemfile and run bundle install
gem "nested_form"
```

In view:-

```
<%= nested_form_for @survey do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :questions do |question| %>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-12 control-label" for="">Title</label>
            <p><%= question.text_field :title %></p>
            <%= question.link_to_remove "Remove this answer" %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.link_to_add "Add more questions", :questions %>
<% end %>
```